# Rest Service To Send An Image

Tags: rest

We have stored images of users in a database, and we have exposed the rest services to read the images. Now how it works is that if I invoke the rest service in a browser, the browser directly displays the image in the browser. I directly send the image as a rest response. Now we want to send some other attributes like does the user has image associated and  so on. So we decided to create a bean with attributes like that, and an byte array. The byte array contains the binary content of the image. Is it possible to achieve as mentioned, can we reconstruct the image in the client side with the binary array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, definitely it is possible to send images through Rest service and client of calling service can use that image. What you have to do is, convert your binary data to Base64 encoded string and set the proper content type and then return this response from your Rest service.