# Smalltalk/seaside REST service return image

Tags: rest, smalltalk, seaside

I'm learning Smalltalk / Seaside and I'm trying to return a picture from a REST service. I'm reading the [seaside book](http://book.seaside.st/book/advanced/restful/getting-started) on REST services. There is an example in the [book](http://book.seaside.st/book/fundamentals/forms/fileupload) on file uploading, but there is no example on how return a file or an image from a REST service.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14579776/rest-service-to-send-an-image) here on SO, but I don't know how to implement this in seaside (yet).

As a proof of concept or 'the simplest thing that could possibly work' I want to return a picture which I read from disk. As a result I want to show the image on a webpage. Any ideas on how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its late but still (was working on something similar)

Create your WARestfullHandler sub-class say ImageGetter and define method

```
getImage
    <get>
    <produces: 'image/png'>
    | file image |
    [ 
     file := (FileSystem workingDirectory / 'myImage.png') readStream binary.
     image := file contents ]
     ensure: [ file close ].
   ^ image
```

Now register the endpoint using

```
WAAdmin register: ImageGetter at: 'images'
```

on calling images/getImage you will receive the image to be displayed on browser.

> https://code.google.com/p/seaside/wiki/SeasideRest

The above url will give you more options/info.